# Vuforia in AR view shows black screen in iOS device

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, vuforia

i am trying to use Vuforia SDK to build an AR application using Unity. The application i build is working fine on the Android device. Whereas the same code  is giving me a black screen in AR view  when i build for iOS.

The version of Unity used for developing the code is 2017.4.1f1 and Xcode version is 10.1. Can some one help me to understand the reason for this;

I have also followed the steps provided in the below video link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3roMSonIG5c

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not using ARkit, you can just downgrade the unity version to 5.6.6 and install the older version of vuforia, the camera black out problem can be solve. This issue is due to vuforia problem.

Comment: my application actually uses ARKit i am targeting for both the technologies marker as well as markerless.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i could resolve this issue after migrating it to Unity 2018.2.16. In addition to that pl. ensure that 
a. Vuforia ticked in the XR settings in the player settings, 
b. AR camera in the inspector is set as main camera